# php header issues in iis7

Tags: php, iis, header

i have change the header status in my php file

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
```

this code run in windows server. no issues for inside window server. but not run the out side of window server. please help me for this issues...

Comment: What do you mean "outside of window server" and what exactly "doesn't run"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure where you picked up the idea, but if you're going to provide *that style* of HTTP header, you need to use a *specific* format [as documented on the `header` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);
```

In particular, it *has* to start with `'HTTP/'` and then an HTTP version number.  `1.0` and `1.1` are safe numbers to use.

Because you're on IIS, that means you're on FastCGI.  This means that you must also insert a `Status` header:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);
header('Status: 404');
```

Comment: hi charles thanks for reply i have do this code also but not working    header('Status: 404');